# bootstrap 3 dropdown menu and carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu and a carousel to my web page. So far theyve been added, meaning the icon for the menu is there and the first picture of the carousel is on the page but when I click on the dropdown menu...... nothing happens! same with the carousel. can anyone help.
Here is the code for the carousel:

```
 <!DOCTYPEhtml>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
  content="width-device-width, intial-scale=1">

    <title>Daniel Vaughan</title>
<!--Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Archivo+Narrow|Barlow|Cabin|Courgette|Dancing+Script|Kanit|Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- bootstrap.3 css -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
  </script>

<style>

Body{
  background-image:url(images/Omen-Background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Barlow','arial', 'Cabin';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar{
  background-image: inherit;
  color:inherit;
}

    #aboutme{
        margin: 50px 40px 40px 50px;
        padding: 50px 25px 25px 50px;
        background-image: inherit;
        color: grey;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
        font-family: 'Barlow';
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    p{
        background: rgba("204, 204, 204, 0.5";
        color: grey;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
    <img class="title-logo" src="images/omen-digital.jpg" height="70px" width="100x" alt="Omen logo">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
          <h1 class="text-super">Daniel Vaughan</h1>
          <h4>Freelance Developer</h4>

        </div>
        </div>
<header>
      <div class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <a href="danvaughan.html"><li>Home</li></a>
       <a href="projects.html"><li>Projects</li></a>
       <a href="employment.html"><li>Employment History</li></a>
       <a href="hobbies.html"><li>Hobbies</li></a>
      </ul>
      </div>
</div>

</header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators black">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to ="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to ="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-sldie-to ="2"></li>
      <li data-targert="#myCarousel" data-slide-to ="3"></li>
    </ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/family.jpg"  style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First family holiday</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img class="image-responsive" src="images/thebar.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>My Favourite Hobbie</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img class="image-responsive" src="images/light-bringer.jpg" style="width=100%">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Some of my favourite books</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="image-responsive" src="images/omen-digital.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Gaming (my second favourite hobbie)</h3>
      </div>
</div>

  <a class="left carousel-control"href="#myCarousel"data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6 text-left" id="aboutme">
        <h1> A Little About Me</h1>
            <p class="text-left">Hello<br/> My name is Daniel Vaughan (Dan). Welcome to my website.</p>

            <p class="text-left">I am a freelance web developer based in Birmingham UK. I have gained experience in the field of web development through the good people  at Freecode camp, where I learned how to code. I love coding.<br/> It gives me great satisfaction when I make websites that are responsive and beautiful.At the moment I am in the market for part-time work as I am still employed as a machine operator.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $("document").ready(function(){
            $("#item").click(function(){
                $("#submenu").slideToggle(500);
            });

        });


    </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add.  In source https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js     and   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js  ??

Comment: If so.  Div id schould be like that div id="myCarousel"  and data-target="#myCarousel"

Comment: I did, I made the corrections you suggested, but im still stuck on the first picture? any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't include bootstrap's javascript file, which is also part of the library. I would recommend you to include on your code the appropriate link from this CDN to see if that helps your problem:

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

**For bootstrap 4:**
 - https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

Copy on your footer:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**For bootstrap 3.3.7:**
 - https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
Copy on your footer:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So. Thank for your code i make some changes and it works fine for me. you missd some "space bars" ";" and i change your links to source code.  Just edit my code to change pictures, and have a good evening :D

```
     <!DOCTYPEhtml>
     <head>


    <title>Daniel Vaughan</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Archivo+Narrow|Barlow|Cabin|Courgette|Dancing+Script|Kanit|Questrial" rel="stylesheet">

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    </script>

    <style>

    body{
    background-image:url(images/Omen-Background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    color: red;
     font-family: 'Barlow','arial', 'Cabin';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    }

    .navbar{
     background-image: inherit;
     color:inherit;
     }

    #aboutme{
        margin: 50px 40px 40px 50px;
        padding: 50px 25px 25px 50px;
        background-image: inherit;
        color: grey;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
        font-family: 'Barlow';
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    p{
        background: rgba("204, 204, 204, 0.5");
        color: grey;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

        <body>
     <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
     <img class="title-logo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_paris.jpg" height="70px" width="100x" alt="Omen logo">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
          <h1 class="text-super">Daniel Vaughan</h1>
          <h4>Freelance Developer</h4>

        </div>
        </div>
<header>
      <div class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <a href="danvaughan.html"><li>Home</li></a>
       <a href="projects.html"><li>Projects</li></a>
       <a href="employment.html"><li>Employment History</li></a>
       <a href="hobbies.html"><li>Hobbies</li></a>
      </ul>
      </div>
</div>

</header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators black">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to ="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to ="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-sldie-to ="2"></li>
      <li data-targert="#myCarousel" data-slide-to ="3"></li>
    </ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg"  width="100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First family holiday</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img class="image-responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg" width="100%">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>My Favourite Hobbie</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img class="image-responsive" src="https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/images/lakeandballoon.jpg" width="100%">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Some of my favourite books</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img class="image-responsive" src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" width="100%">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Gaming (my second favourite hobbie)</h3>
      </div>
</div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6 text-left" id="aboutme">
        <h1> A Little About Me</h1>
            <p class="text-left">Hello<br/> My name is Daniel Vaughan (Dan). Welcome to my website.</p>

            <p class="text-left">I am a freelance web developer based in Birmingham UK. I have gained experience in the field of web development through the good people  at Freecode camp, where I learned how to code. I love coding.<br/> It gives me great satisfaction when I make websites that are responsive and beautiful.At the moment I am in the market for part-time work as I am still employed as a machine operator.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $("document").ready(function(){
            $("#item").click(function(){
                $("#submenu").slideToggle(500);
            });

        });


    </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: still not working, and when i change the href to src all the images from the slide are displayed as well as the drop down menu contents. so i changed the link back to href and it go back to the hiding everything else but not working just jumping back up to the top on the first image.

Comment: Just copy my code. And change  <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg"   for <img src=" picture.jpg"    you don't need to change anything more.  Just change my pictures for yours

Comment: you sir are a legend. works absolutely perfectly now.

Comment: O thsnks. So now you can mark my answer as helpful 